# Bundle Cover not shown when first

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I have a bundle with a timeline card inside.  The main timeline card which I want to be the cover is set to be the cover(isBundleCover=true).  However when the cards are inserted and the user taps to see or looks up to activate the display the inner bundle card(not cover) is shown first.  Is there a way to show the cover first?  Is this acting as intended?  I've tried changing the order of cards inserted and did not make a difference.

```
            Credential credential = AuthUtil.getCredential(id);
            Mirror service = MirrorClient.getMirror(credential);

            boolean newNotification = false;
            TimelineItem timelineItem = null;
            TimelineItem notesTimelineItem = null;
            List<TimelineItem> oldCards = null;
                oldCards = service.timeline().list()
                        .setBundleId(String.valueOf(call.getId()))
                        .execute().getItems();


            if (oldCards != null)

            if (oldCards.size() < 1) {

                timelineItem = new TimelineItem();
                notesTimelineItem = new TimelineItem();
                timelineItem.setId(String.valueOf(call.getId()));
                timelineItem.setBundleId(String.valueOf(call.getId()));
                notesTimelineItem.setBundleId(String.valueOf(call.getId()));
                timelineItem.setIsBundleCover(true);
                newNotification = true;
                timelineItem.setHtml(TimeLineHTMLFactory.getDispatchCard(               call.getType(), call.getAddress(), call.getUnits(),String.valueOf(call.getLat() / 1E6), String.valueOf(call.getLongi() / 1E6)));
                if (call.getNotes().contentEquals("")) {
                    notesTimelineItem.setText("Notes not available");
                } else {
                    notesTimelineItem.setText(call.getNotes());
                    notesTimelineItem.setTitle("Notes");
                }
                notesTimelineItem.setSourceItemId("notes");
                Location incident = new Location();
                incident.setLatitude(call.getLat() / 1E6);

                incident.setLongitude(call.getLongi() / 1E6);
                notesTimelineItem.setLocation(incident);
                List<MenuItem> menuItemList = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

                menuItemList.add(new MenuItem().setAction("NAVIGATE"));
                menuItemList.add(new MenuItem().setAction("TOGGLE_PINNED"));

                notesTimelineItem.setMenuItems(menuItemList);
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < oldCards.size(); ++i) {
                    log.log(Level.WARNING, "updating oldCard: "
                            + oldCards.get(i).getId());
                    log.log(Level.WARNING,"sourceItemId: "+oldCards.get(i).getSourceItemId());
                    boolean isCover=false;
                    try{
                        isCover=oldCards.get(i).getIsBundleCover();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        log.log(Level.WARNING,"Exception getting isBundleCover: "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                    if (isCover) {
                        // MAIN DISPATCH CARD

                        oldCards.get(i)
                                .setHtml(
                                        TimeLineHTMLFactory.getDispatchCard(
                                                call.getType(), call
                                                        .getAddress(), call
                                                        .getUnits(),
                                                String.valueOf(call
                                                        .getLat() / 1E6),
                                                String.valueOf(call
                                                        .getLongi() / 1E6)));

                    } else if (oldCards.get(i).getSourceItemId()
                            .contains("notes")) {

                        if (call.getNotes().contentEquals("")) {
                            oldCards.get(i).setText("Notes not available");
                        } else {
                            oldCards.get(i).setText(call.getNotes());

                        }
                        oldCards.get(i).setTitle("Notes");
                        Location incident = new Location();
                        incident.setLatitude(call.getLat() / 1E6);
                        incident.setLongitude(call.getLongi() / 1E6);

                        if(incident!=null){
                        oldCards.get(i).setLocation(incident);
                        }
                        List<MenuItem> menuItemList = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

                        menuItemList.add(new MenuItem()
                                .setAction("NAVIGATE"));
                        menuItemList.add(new MenuItem()
                                .setAction("TOGGLE_PINNED"));

                        oldCards.get(i).setMenuItems(menuItemList);
                    }
                }
            }

                if (oldCards.size() > 0) {
                    for (TimelineItem card : oldCards) {

                        log.log(Level.WARNING,
                                "oldCard id: " + card.getId()
                                        + " bundleid: "
                                        + card.getBundleId());
                        service.timeline().update(card.getId(), card)
                                .execute();
                    }
                } else {
                log.log(Level.INFO, "New notification here");
    timelineItem.setNotification(new NotificationConfig().setLevel("DEFAULT"));
    MirrorClient.insertTimelineItem(credential, notesTimelineItem);
    MirrorClient.insertTimelineItem(credential, timelineItem);
}
```

JSON for Cover card:

> {
>     "kind": "mirror#timelineItem",
>     "id": "710a9f44-92e7-463e-801d-940b59aebb8e",
>     "bundleId": "5808701407494144",
>     "isBundleCover": true,
>     "created": "2013-10-28T13:30:19.160Z",
>     "updated": "2013-10-28T13:30:19.160Z",
>     "etag": "1382967019160",
>     "html": "\n  \n    \n\n  \n  \n  \n          **E M S**\n          \n**741 PARK AVE**\n\n
>
> \n  \n\n",
>     "notification": {
>       "level": "DEFAULT"
>     }
>   }

JSON for Notes Card:

```
{
  "kind": "mirror#timelineItem",
  "id": "cfd7173f-4757-4e2e-9f2e-fbcbba2c0e99",
  "bundleId": "5948571312455680",
  "created": "2013-10-28T13:30:09.904Z",
  "updated": "2013-10-28T13:30:09.904Z",
  "etag": "1382967009904",
  "title": "Notes",
  "text": "Notes go in here...",
  "location": {
  "kind": "mirror#location",
  "latitude": 37.922223,
  "longitude": -87.805731
},
  "menuItems": [
{
  "action": "NAVIGATE"
},
{
    "action": "TOGGLE_PINNED"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Would you mind posting the code or JSON for all of the timeline items in your bundle?

Comment: just to clarify, if the user scrolls in the timeline to the card it works as expected.  But if the user looks up or taps to view the new notification the inner bundle card(note card) is shown.

Comment: also while your here @JennyMurphy - getIsBundleCover() will return null if that value is not set.  That is why I have the exception handling.  I'll create a entry on issue tracker if that is something that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears this a bug.  Create ticket on tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=233

Answer (score 0):

I think you are halfway there, I would add the bundle cover last and then isBundleCover=True.

See below.

To bundle timeline items, create them with the same value for bundleId. The most recently added item is the bundle's cover card.

Note: To set a specific timeline item as the bundle cover card, set its isBundleCover property to true.

Comment: I am adding bundle cover last and isBundleCover=true is set.  Still displays inner card first.

Comment: I think you have discovered a bug!  Congrats!  I can recreate this 100% with bundled cards.

Comment: seems that way!  created bug here :  https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=233&thanks=233&ts=1383067998

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. When bundles are inserted you will be displayed the most recently inserted card within the bundle.

If you'd like to display a collection of cards, consider using [HTML Pagination](https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#paginating) instead. Your markup for a card might look something like this:

```
<article class="cover-only">
 <section>
   <p>Cover page</p>
 </section>
</article>

<article>
 <section>
   <p>Second page</p>
 </section>
</article>

<article>
 <section>
   <p>Third page</p>
 </section>
</article>
```